# Does Ubuntu 20.04 work in Azure?

Tags: 20.04, compatibility, azure

Does Azure support Ubuntu 20.04? We are deploying a new syslog and were opting for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Does it meet the 20.04 minimum specs? The only way to know for sure is try it. System Requirements for Ubuntu 20.04
2 GHz dual-core processor.
4 GiB RAM (but 1 GiB can work)
25 GB of hard-drive space.
VGA capable of 1024×768 screen resolution.
Either of the two: a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media.
Optionally, Internet access is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

[Ubuntu Pro for Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/canonical.0001-com-ubuntu-pro-focal?tab=overview) is a premium image designed by Canonical optimized for production environments running on Azure. It includes security and compliance services, enabled by default, in a form suitable for small to large-scale Linux enterprise operations — with no contract needed.

**Key features**

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, optimised for Azure with the 5.4 Linux kernel out of the box
- Automatic security updates applied to 28,000+ packages including Apache Kafka, NGINX, MongoDB, Redis and PostgreSQL
- CIS hardened Ubuntu with CIS automation tooling to establish a security baseline across all your systems
- 10-year lifetime support: Ubuntu Pro 20.04 LTS provides extended maintenance through 2030

<sub>**source:** [Ubuntu Pro 20.04 LTS for Azure](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/canonical.0001-com-ubuntu-pro-focal?tab=overview)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> Does Azure support Ubuntu 20.04? We are deploying a new syslog and were opting for Ubuntu 18.04.

Yes. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is available in the Azure Marketplace. There are two official images for 20.04 server made available by Canonical:

- [Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-gb/marketplace/apps/canonical.0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal?tab=Overview), which has no software cost; and
- [Ubuntu Pro 20.04 LTS](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-gb/marketplace/apps/canonical.0001-com-ubuntu-pro-focal?tab=Overview), which extends Ubuntu Server with a number of additional security services/tools etc and has an hourly cost, as mentioned by karel.

You can see more information and pointers to the latest Ubuntu Azure Marketplace images [here](https://ubuntu.com/azure).

Note: I am assuming that you mean "does Ubuntu 20.04 run on Azure". If you are actually asking whether Azure *supports* Ubuntu in the sense that they will answer technical queries on Ubuntu, you will need to check your contract with Microsoft. Normally, people who want SLAed Ubuntu technical support for Ubuntu workloads/within VMs (on private clouds or on the public clouds like Azure) will want a separate support contract with someone like Canonical (the makers of Ubuntu) -- though this can often also be transacted via the public cloud as a Private Offer or similar. See the datasheet for Ubuntu Pro on Azure available [here](https://ubuntu.com/azure/pro).